# Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 maven in windows 10

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am using maven in my web test automation project and configuring using pom.xml but getting dependencies error as 
Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0
Can someone quickly suggest how to resolve this ?

Using windows 10 OS and C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\lib is where I tried to look initially for tools.jar but was not available and later I downloaded and kept it here and 
restarted eclipse but still the same error . 
     now

```
 Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0
```

Regards,
Deep

Comment: I suppose the dependency to tools jar is defined via system scope dependency (apart from being deprecated for a long time) this will not work on JDK9+ This will simply not work..The question is why a tools jar is needed? Without the full project and the pom file it's hard to tell what might need to be changed...

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response . But thing is when I removed also now tools.jar now from the lib folder and removed the dependency tag also for tools.jar but I could see there is an error now in   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">   . Can you please suggest.

Comment: This project has to be migrated and fixed...I don't know the project nor the code etc.